# Why do you not pass a parameter to authlogic's UserSession.find function

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic

To find a user session in authlogic, you call `UserSession.find` (or whatever you named `UserSession`). Is the ability to find the correct `UserSession` without providing a parameter (something like `UserSession.find(params['session_id']`) a Rails thing or did authlogic overwrite the `find` functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UserSession isn't an ActiveRecord model. Instead, it inherits from `Authlogic::Session::Base`. This provides it with methods which are similar to an ORM. The [authlogic docs](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic#quick-rails-example) state:

```
What if creating sessions worked like an ORM library on the surface…
```

The `find` method is defined within the authlogic codebase [here](https://github.com/binarylogic/authlogic/blob/master/lib/authlogic/session/persistence.rb#L36-L45), which just probes the session store (usually a cookie) to see if the user is logged in.